# Android 6 Permission access to internet

Tags: android, android-permissions

month ago I wrote my first app and I put permission to write on sd-card, when activity start i request permission i do:

```
if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("L'app richiede i permessi di scrittura")
                .setTitle("Richiesta Permessi");

        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                makeRequest();
            }
        });

        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();

    } else {
        makeRequest();
    }
}
```

this is `makeRequest()`

```
private static final int REQUEST_WRITE_STORAGE = 112;
private static String TAG = "PermissionDemo";

protected void makeRequest() {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
            REQUEST_WRITE_STORAGE);
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_WRITE_STORAGE: {
            if (grantResults.length == 0
                    || grantResults[0] !=
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

               //Log.i(TAG, "Permission has been denied by user");

                finish();
            } else {
                //Log.i(TAG, "Permission has been granted by user");
                creaConfigurazioneIniziale();
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Now my app have need permission for internet i have put this on manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

and this

but don't work, what i can do to add permission for Internet and network?
I have try to add `makereqeust` this:

```
protected void makeRequest() {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
            REQUEST_WRITE_STORAGE);
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.INTERNET},
            REQUEST_WRITE_STORAGE);
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE},
            REQUEST_WRITE_STORAGE);
}
```

but don't work. How i can do to solve problem?

Comment: you dont need to ask for internet and access_network_state permission....check this https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en

Comment: Did you add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> to your Manifest?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You don't need to ask for internet or access_network_state permission because Android grant it by default.

there are some dangerous permissions which we have to check

### List of Dangerous Permissions

> **CALENDAR :** READ_CALENDAR, WRITE_CALENDAR
>
> **CAMERA :** CAMERA
>
> **CONTACTS :** READ_CONTACTS, WRITE_CONTACTS, GET_ACCOUNTS
>
> **LOCATION :** ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
>
> **MICROPHONE :** RECORD_AUDIO
>
> **PHONE :** READ_PHONE_STATE, CALL_PHONE, READ_CALL_LOG, WRITE_CALL_LOG, ADD_VOICEMAIL, USE_SIP, PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS
>
> **SENSORS :** BODY_SENSORS
>
> **SMS :** SEND_SMS, RECEIVE_SMS, READ_SMS, RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH, RECEIVE_MMS
>
> **STORAGE :** READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

### List of Normal Permissions

> ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS
>
> ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
>
> ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY
>
> ACCESS_WIFI_STATE
>
> BLUETOOTH
>
> BLUETOOTH_ADMIN
>
> BROADCAST_STICKY
>
> CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE
>
> CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE
>
> CHANGE_WIFI_STATE
>
> DISABLE_KEYGUARD
>
> EXPAND_STATUS_BAR
>
> FLASHLIGHT
>
> GET_PACKAGE_SIZE
>
> INTERNET
>
> KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES
>
> MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS
>
> NFC
>
> READ_SYNC_SETTINGS
>
> READ_SYNC_STATS
>
> RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED
>
> REORDER_TASKS
>
> REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES
>
> SET_TIME_ZONE
>
> SET_WALLPAPER
>
> SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS
>
> TRANSMIT_IR
>
> USE_FINGERPRINT
>
> VIBRATE
>
> WAKE_LOCK
>
> WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS
>
> SET_ALARM
>
> INSTALL_SHORTCUT
>
> UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT

For more information check this out. [Normal and Dangerous Permissions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous)

### How to Check for dangerous permissions?

I am posting code the way i did. Let's say we what to check for `CAMARA` permission.

```
public class Utility {

    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA = 130;

    public static boolean checkPermissionCAMERA(final Context context) {
        int currentAPIVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if (currentAPIVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                    Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) context,
                        Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                    alertBuilder.setCancelable(true);
                    alertBuilder.setTitle("Permission necessary");
                    alertBuilder.setMessage("Camera permission is necessary");
                    alertBuilder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context,
                                    new String[] { Manifest.permission.CAMERA }, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA);
                        }
                    });
                    AlertDialog alert = alertBuilder.create();
                    alert.show();

                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[] { Manifest.permission.CAMERA },
                            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA);
                }
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public static void showDialogOK(final Activity context, String message) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        alertBuilder.setCancelable(true);
        alertBuilder.setTitle("Permission necessary");
        alertBuilder.setMessage(message);
        alertBuilder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Utility.checkAndRequestPermissions(context);
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = alertBuilder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
}
```

Now inside your Activity.

```
if(Utility.checkPermissionCAMERA(this)){
    // Do work
}
```

and finally override `onRequestPermissionsResult`

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
        String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
    case Utility.MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA:
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Splash_Activity.this,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // do work
        }else{
            // take action
        } 
        break;
    }
}
```

### EDIT:

How to Check for multiple permissions?

```
public class Utility {

    public static final int REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS = 101;

    public static boolean checkAndRequestPermissions(final Activity context) {
        int ExtstorePermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        int WExtstorePermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        int cameraPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
        int READ_PHONE_STATE = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
        int location = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        int READ_CONTACTS = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS);
        int RECORD_AUDIO = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);
        int internet = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                Manifest.permission.INTERNET);
        List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();
        if (cameraPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
        }
        if (WExtstorePermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded
                    .add(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }
        if (ExtstorePermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded
                    .add(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }
        if (location != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        }
        if (READ_PHONE_STATE != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
        }
        if (READ_CONTACTS != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS);
        }
        if (RECORD_AUDIO != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);
        }
        if (internet != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.INTERNET);
        }
        if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(context, listPermissionsNeeded
                    .toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]),
                    REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void showDialogOK(final Activity context, String message) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        alertBuilder.setCancelable(true);
        alertBuilder.setTitle("Permission necessary");
        alertBuilder.setMessage(message);
        alertBuilder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Utility.checkAndRequestPermissions(context);
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = alertBuilder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
}
```

I hope this will help

Comment: therefore i mus only add to manifest permission for: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> and <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> right? if i want add dangerous permission to my code how i do?

Comment: If i want to require multi dangerous permission at the same time, How i have do?

Comment: Where did you get this info (about which permissions are normal and which are dangerous)? It is NOT available here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#normal-dangerous ... Huge thanks for your answer!

Comment: @LeoLeontev it was mentioned in that article. I guess they have removed or updated it.

Answer (score 2):

Please check [link1](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html), [link2](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/index.html#overview)

It is still mandatory for apps that will access the Internet. If a developer were to publish an app without defining it in the Android manifest, an exception will be thrown the first time a connection attempt is made, and the app will possibly crash. This is no different than before.

Limited Permissions Granted at Install Time: When the user installs or updates the app, the system grants the app all permissions that the app requests that fall under PROTECTION_NORMAL. For example, alarm clock and internet permissions fall under PROTECTION_NORMAL, so they are automatically granted at install time.

Thanks