# File creation failing without exception

Tags: java, android

I'm attempting to create a blank file in an Android app. My code is working fine on Android 5, but when I tested with Android 7 or higher it fails without printing an exception.

My code is:

```
downloadLocation = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + "folder" + System.currentTimeMillis());
downloadLocation.mkdir();

downloadFile = new File(downloadLocation, "file" + System.currentTimeMillis());
downloadFile.createNewFile();
```

Note, I have declared the variables and everything, I just didn't include that. Both the downloadLocation and downloadFile variables are File type.

On the Android 5 physical device that I was using, it worked just fine. I then tested with an Android 7 virtual device, but it fails without printing an error in the log. The issue is with the second block of code, specifically the last line. I know this because I placed a log between each line and every log outputs except for the log after the file is created.

It's very hard to debug something when there is no error displayed, dispite there being a catch error that is suppose to print the stack trace and the exception.

Any ideas?

Just as a note, I know that the file and folder don't already exist because I've appended a time stamp to the name to prevent that for testing purposes, since I know 100% that the file will have a unique name in release. That's why I haven't encased each block in an if statement that would check to make sure that the file/folder doesn't already exist.

Comment: runtime permissions

Comment: so what do you see on the `logcat`? just nothing? or at least something like `"process xxxx died"` or similar?

Comment: @pskink Nothing (other than the manual debug text strings that I inserted myself). The app doesn't crash because the file creation is done within a try/catch statement that's supposed to print the exception into logcat, but it doesn't, despite the catch code being triggered and running.

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh What do you mean? Does Android 7 and higher require higher permissions? I did see a while ago that Android 7 changed how file sharing worked, but I thought that was only when accessing the file after creation and only when sharing a file between a different app or different thread.

Comment: Try adding break points and attaching the debugger so you can see exactly what's happening and where it is going at each step. Are you intending to use this directory privately for your app only? You may want to change it to getExternalFilesDir instead and you won't need to request write permissions

Comment: so post your whole current code (with `try / catch`)

Comment: @pskink it's just the standard `try { CODE } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }` I did add a manual debug string to the catch block though (to make sure that the catch block is being executed) and it's being triggered, although the printStackTrace is not actually printing anything.

Comment: most need  run time permission  above 6.0 so permission give run time your problem will solve.

Comment: @TheAndroidProgrammer after android 6.0 you have to implement runtime time check for critical permissions in your case it is `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40131044/5148289)

Comment: @V-rundPuro-hit You mean like this documentation page says? https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

Comment: @TheAndroidProgrammer yes Exactly

Comment: so what do you see if you call `Log.d(TAG, "inside catch block", e);`? or at least `Log.d(TAG, "inside catch block: " + e.getMessage());`?

Comment: Probable you havent given runtime permissions

Comment: Thanks all for the help! This is the first app that I've made that requires a dangerous permission, so I had no idea that you had to trigger the permission dialogs manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is probably throwing a file not found exception. After `downloadLocation.mkdir()` call:

```
if (downloadLocation.exists()) { System.out.println("File Exists"); }
```

You'll notice the message won't print. This is because you never had permissions to write to the directory.

Add the following to your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

An easy way to handle requesting permissions is a great library: [EasyPermissions](https://github.com/googlesamples/easypermissions)

Using EasyPermissions, your code might look like:

1.) You call a function in your activity to trigger creating the file:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    writeFiles();
}
```

2.) writeFiles will need to ensure permissions are granted before executing the file operations:

```
@AfterPermissionGranted(PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE)
private void writeFiles() {
    String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
    if (EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(this, permissions)) {
        try {
            File downloadLocation = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + "folder" + System.currentTimeMillis());
            downloadLocation.mkdir();

            if (downloadLocation.exists()) {
                Log.i("writeFiles()", downloadLocation.getAbsolutePath());
            }

            File downloadFile = new File(downloadLocation, "file" + System.currentTimeMillis());
            downloadFile.createNewFile();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    } else {
        // Do not have permissions, request them now
        EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(this, "Your permission rationale", PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE, permissions);
    }
}
```

3.) In order for EasyPermissions to automatically call writeFiles() again after permissions are granted, you'll need to add this override:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    // Forward results to EasyPermissions
    EasyPermissions.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults, this);
}
```

You'll notice `PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE` used a couple of times. This is just a constant integer you use to identify the permissions requests when onRequestPermissionsResult is called from the Activity. This can really be any number you want (such as 1000) so long as it's unique. I linked to the documentation of EasyPermissions which will further explain how it works, but this greatly simplifies how you handle runtime permissions.

**Edit:**
The following links will help explain more about requesting permissions for your apps:

- https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting
- https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#normal-dangerous
- [Android Marshmallow 6.0: Asking For Permission](https://youtu.be/iZqDdvhTZj0)

In the past, when users would install your app in the Play Store they would be presented with a list of the permissions your app wants. If the user proceeded to install the app, all permissions were automatically granted. Android 6 changed this and now users are given more control over which permissions they want to grant each app.

Some permissions still don't need user approval, these are qualified as *normal permissions*. An example would be the `INTERNET` permission. Other permissions that could affect privacy, system data, etc... are considered *dangerous permissions* and will require the user to grant them via the permissions dialog as seen above. The second URL I posted above will show you some tables of what each permission is qualified as.

Keep in mind if users deny a permission and check the "Don't show again" box then the dialog will never be shown to them again and they will have to go to the App in the system Settings and grant the permission from there. If you ever want to help the user get to this screen you can use the following intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
intent.setData(Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: you shout add `onRequestPermissionsResult` method as well in your answer

Comment: Yeah, I'm putting together a full permissions example now

Comment: Had to believe that I've been developing Android apps for over two years and I have never worked with a permission before. Had no idea that you had to manually trigger the permission dialog. Thanks for the help!

Comment: There's always something new to learn :)
I'll update the end of my answer with another link but as of Android 6 and higher permissions flagged as dangerous will require explicit user approval.